# Is there a way to iterate through list of string in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iterator

I wrote the following code. I want to replace the number "1" with "0" whenever it appear twice or more for a particular universal_id and the number "1" that is left should be in the row where days are the lowest. The below code does the work but I want to iterate over more then one universal_id. Column "e" is ok for 'efra" I want this to do for other ID's and other columns.

```
pdf1 = pd.DataFrame(
    [[1, 0,1, 0,1, 60, 'fdaf'],
     [1, 1,0, 0,1, 350, 'fdaf'],
     [1, 1,0, 0,1, 420, 'erfa'],
     [0, 1,0, 0,1, 410, 'erfa']],
    columns=['A', 'B', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'days','universal_id'])

pdf1['A'] = np.where(pdf1['days']==pdf1['days'].min(),1,0)
zet = pdf1.loc[pdf1['e'].isin([1]) & 
pdf1['universal_id'].str.contains('erfa')]
zet['e'] = np.where(zet['days']==zet['days'].min(),1,0)
pdf1.loc[zet.index, :] = zet[:]
pdf1
```

Output:

```
    A   B   c   d   e   days    universal_id
 0  1   0   1   0   1   60     fdaf
 1  0   1   0   0   1   350    fdaf
 2  0   1   0   0   0   420    erfa
 3  0   1   0   0   1   410    erfa
```

Comment: Can you add expected ouput from sample data?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: why is not in A oupout `1,0,0,1` ?

Comment: You are wright jezrael it should be 1,0,0,1

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
df2 = pdf1.sort_values(by='days')

m1 = df2['A'].eq(1)
m2 = df2[['A', 'universal_id']].duplicated()

pdf1.loc[m1&m2, 'A'] = 0
```

output:

```
   A  B  c  d  e  days universal_id
0  1  0  1  0  1    60         fdaf
1  0  1  0  0  1   350         fdaf
2  1  1  0  0  1   420         erfa
3  0  1  0  0  1   410         erfa
```

for e, f you want to follow the same logic:

```
m1 = df2['A'].eq(1)
m3 = df2[['e', 'universal_id']].duplicated()

pdf1.loc[m1&m3, 'e'] = 0
```

output:

```
   A  B  c  d  e  days universal_id
0  1  0  1  0  1    60         fdaf
1  0  1  0  0  0   350         fdaf
2  1  1  0  0  0   420         erfa
3  0  1  0  0  1   410         erfa
```